# What is (do) for here?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-inversion, negative-polarity-items

I know that if do come between the pronoun and the verb, it makes the verb stronger. Does it work the same if it came before the verb.
This is the text:

> Only after the trucks have passed through my street and the people quiet down **do** I go home. When I get there, I am confused to find my whole family packing.

Answer (score 5):

*Only* often triggers "inversion", where the subject and verb switch places. A simpler example of that might be:

> Only later are we told why.

(meaning "We aren't told why until later"), with "are we" instead of "we are".

In your example, this involves inserting *do*, exactly the same as in questions:

> When do I go home?

---

Incidentally, this inversion is not specific to *only*, but also happens with various other negative and negative-like adverbs:

> Never have so many birds been seen in one place.
>
> Rarely do they disagree about anything important.
>
> Nowhere else are pencils more expensive than bicycles.